# Trouble coming up with a substitution when integrating $\sqrt{5 - 4\cos(t)}$ w.r.t. t

Tags: calculus

I can't seem to come up with any trick to solve this integral, and apparently neither can Wolfram alpha. The whole integral is of the form $3\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{5 - 4\cos(t)}dt$. How should I proceed?

Comment: These are what we call "elliptic integral" and can't be computed algebraically.

Comment: You can convert this into a complete elliptic integral of the second kind - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral

Comment: @Surb & Math Lover, thanks for the tip!